# What are steps required to compile Octave on Windows as shared lib for use in development?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, octave

I want to use [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) in my C++ app. I downloaded latest source Release [from here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html)
 but I do not get how to build it and get some `lib` folder for dlls and `include` folder for includes.

So how to build Octave for integration into an app - as a shared, or better, a static library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [guide to building Octave with MinGW](http://octave.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/octave/trunk/octave-forge/admin/Windows/mingw32/HOWTO.txt) on the Subversion repository.